# Prefilled value of the password field in the form?

Tags: php, html

I have a page in my website in which there is a button For E.g **Login To FB** When I click on it I need to open a new page in which form values are automatically pre-filled. To accomplish this I am using below code:

```
<form method="post" action="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">
    <input type="hidden" name="username" value="XYZ">
    <input type="hidden" name="password"    value="123456">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><span >Login to FB</span></button>
</form>
```

By using this code, it redirects to login page but only username is pre-filled with value not the password field. Password field is empty. So, how I can accomplish that password field should contain value which I am passing through my website. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. What are you _actually_ trying to achieve? How did you get to this as a solution? I mean, taking your example code at face value, you can't force Facebook to populate _their_ password input with a random value from a POST request (not directly anyway afaik, there are ways like emulating browsers, but that seems outside the scope).

Comment: That would be a bit of a security risk. The username is probably pre-filled from the browser, not from your form. Your form will be doing a form submit to facebook.com, which probably doesn't accept post requests (which is what you're trying to do). There will be CSRF mitigation on their login form to prevent submission from elsewhere. Generally just sounds like a very unsafe practice here.

Answer (score 0):

after spending so much time on this issue, I finally ended with the solution. Actually I have taken 
 `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><span >Login to FB</span></button>` where I have't mentioned any name attribute in it. After changing above line to 
 `<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" name="login"><span >Login to FB</span></button>` it is working fine and automatically login to a website.

Thanks! Hope it helps for other developers also.